# Same code errors in a Stored Procedure, works in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a stored procedure that calls a linked server like below. The column 'datestr' is of type char(8) and is not always properly formatted. It is usually yyyymmdd but since I do not control how that data is formatted, I am using the TRY_CAST to only get rows where I can format it into a date.

Executing the SP gives me the following error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Running the exact same code extracted from the SP in T-SQL returns data without error. I'm certain the issue is with the part of the WHERE clause with the DATEADD function hitting a value that is not able to be CAST into a date but I can't figure out why it runs differently in SP and extracted T-SQL.

I checked the plan using SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON before running both and see some variations. Namely the estimated rows in the working query are much lower in the Remote Query operator (~200K vs. 15 mil)

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[SampleSP]
AS
    SELECT top 50 tbl1.rowID as rowID, 
            year(datestr) as [year],
            month(datestr) as [month],
            count(*) AS CountRow
    FROM   [LinkedSer].[RemoteDB].[dbo].[tbl1] tbl1
        inner join [dbo].[LocalTbl] tbl2 on tbl1.rowID = tbl2.rowID
    WHERE  tbl1.row_type = 'tbl1A' 
    and (TRY_CAST(tbl1.datestr AS date) IS NOT NULL 
        and tbl1.datestr > DATEADD(yy, -10, getdate()))
    group BY tbl1.rowID, year(tbl1.datestr), month(tbl1.datestr)
```

Comment: Why not just `TRY_CAST(tbl1.datestr AS date) > DATEADD(yy, -10, getdate())` *or* better yet, not storing date and time data as a `varchar` (*that* is the real problem)?

Comment: If you "must" (you don't) need to store date and time values in a `varchar` (which, again, you most certainly don't), at least use an ambiguous format that has the same sort order as a date and time value (such as `yyyyMMdd`) and then you can use `varchar` expressions and get similar behaviour. `tbl.yyyyMMddVarcharDate > '20120413'` would at least be SARGable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order the predicates are evaluated is plan-dependent.  So you need to eliminate the potentially-invalid comparison from your code.

And simplifying to:

```
 and TRY_CAST(tbl1.datestr AS date) > DATEADD(yy, -10, getdate())
```

should do the trick.